# Reading image contents using selenium and java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to read content of image using selenium and asprise jars and added below jar files in my project :

- `aocr.jar`
- `AspriseOCR`

and below is my code :

```
          BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\siddhesh.kalgaonkar\\Desktop\\love.jpg"));
          String imageText = new OCR().recognizeCharacters((RenderedImage)image);
          System.out.println("Text From Image : \n"+ imageText);
          System.out.println("Length of total text : \n"+ imageText.length());
```

but its giving below error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no AspriseOCR in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.loadLibrary(OCR.java:247)
    at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.<init>(OCR.java:56)
    at com.image.selenium.ImageVerification.start(ImageVerification.java:52)
```

I also tried setting java.library.path using [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/) link but of no use. Please help anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer to my own question. We can now do it with the help of below information:

- Add latest `aocr.jar` to your project. Download it from 
  [this](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/java-ocr-for-windows-mac-linux-download.html) link.

  - Include **pom.xml** file in your project for maven dependencies and add this dependency :

    ```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.asprise.ocr</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-ocr-api</artifactId>
        <version>[15,)</version>
        </dependency>
    ```
- Write below code in your java file :

  ```
  public class ImageVerification  

  {  
   WebDriver driver;    

      @Test
      public void start() throws IOException {

          Ocr ocr = new Ocr(); // create a new OCR engine
          ocr.startEngine("eng", Ocr.SPEED_FASTEST); // English

          String s = ocr.recognize(new File[] { new File("C:\\Users\\siddhesh.kalgaonkar\\Desktop\\love.jpg") },
                  Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_TEXT, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);
          System.out.println(s);
          ocr.stopEngine();
      }
  ```
- For more details refer [this](http://asprise.com/ocr/docs/html/asprise-ocr-api-java.html) link
  Enjoy :)
  **NOTE**: It works only for images with plain text.It `doesn't` work for images with data in **graph format** or **pie chart** or **trend chart**

Comment: Don't forget to come back and accept this as the answer.

Comment: Yes but I cannot accept now as SO won't allow me before 48 hours